# How do I display the taxonomy term alongside the post type post title?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

I would like to display the taxonomy term of the post type post besides the post type post title, separated by the “in” or "Posted in" text string.

What i tried so far:

```
$output .= '<div>' . get_the_title() . '</div>';
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'itemscategories', array('fields' => 'names'));

echo implode(', ', $terms);
```

---

```
$output .= '<div>' . get_the_title() . '</div>';
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'itemscategories', array('fields' => 'names'));

if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
  echo $terms[0]; 
}
```

---

```
$output .= '<div>' . get_the_title() . '</div>';
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'itemscategories', array('fields' => 'names'));

foreach( $terms as $name ) {
    echo $name.'<br />';
}
```

---

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'itemscategories' );
if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    $output .= '<div>' . esc_html( get_the_title() ) . ' ' . esc_html__( 'Posted in:', 'text_domain' ) . ' ' . esc_html( $terms[0]->name ) . '</div>';
}
```

---

```
$output .= '<div>' . esc_html( get_the_title() ) . get_the_term_list( $post_id, 'itemscategories', 'Posted in: ', ', ' ) . '</div>';
```

---

All the codes just result in white space, nothing displayed.
What am I doing wrong here?

If I put `var_dump( $terms );` before the if statement, this is shown:

```
array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { }
```

WP debug reports `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /home/username(edited_by_OP)/public_html/wp-content/themes/total-child-theme-master/functions.php on line 543`
There is a proper semicolon at the end of the row before the if statement, so I don't know why this error.

This is the shortcode where the code is embedded

```
// Define query
    $query_args = array(
    'author'=> $user_id,
        'post_type'      => 'items', // Change this to the type of post you want to show
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    );

    // Query by term if defined
    if ( $term ) {

        $query_args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field'    => 'ID',
                'terms'    => $term,

            ),
        );

    }

    // Query posts
    $custom_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

    // Add content if we found posts via our query
    if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {

        // Open div wrapper around loop
        $output .= '<div>';

        // Loop through posts
        while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {

            // Sets up post data so you can use functions like get_the_title(), get_permalink(), etc
            $custom_query->the_post();

            // This is the output for your entry so what you want to do for each post.

$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'itemscategories' );
if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    $output .= '<div>' . esc_html( get_the_title() ) . ' ' . esc_html__( 'Posted in:', 'text_domain' ) . ' ' . esc_html( $terms[0]->name ) . '</div>';
}
        }

        // Close div wrapper around loop
        $output .= '</div>';

        // Restore data
        wp_reset_postdata();

    }

    // Return your shortcode output
    return $output;

}
add_shortcode( 'myprefix_custom_grid', 'myprefix_custom_grid_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Please check the function `get_the_term_list`. You will simply have to use `get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'itemscategories', 'Posted in:' );`

Comment: `$output .= '<div>' . esc_html( get_the_title() ) . get_the_term_list( $get_the_ID(), 'itemscategories', 'Posted in: ', ', ' ) . '</div>';` It does not work unfortunately. It results in white space displayed and it breaks the layout of the profile page.

Comment: You have a dollar sign that shouldn't be there: `$get_the_ID()`.

Comment: I removed the dollar sign, and only the titles are displayed. No terms shown.

Comment: Sorry everyone for my stupidity, the posts were not assigned to the taxonomy. Solved!

Comment: But now I would like to show the post title where the post type was posted, instead of the taxonomy, and linking to it. Apperently there is no linking (between post type and the default post where the post types are posted) I could use for the code and maybe I should send some hidden field along with the post to create a link, but this is already done in the form of Gravity Forms “embed url”. I wonder how could I retrieve that url via php?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The posts were not assigned to the taxonomy.